# How to make a python file using a previous version?

Tags: python, exe, python-3.6, pyinstaller, python-3.7

I have Python 3.7 installed, and want to make an .exe out of it, so I'm trying to make a 3.6.5 file so pyinstaller will work on it. How can I make it so the version of python the file uses is 3.6.5 and not 3.7(my default). When I type `python` in cmd it goes in 3.7. When I type `python --version`, it says 3.7. Keep in mind, I typed all of this in the directory of where 3.6.5 is. 3.7 is installed on my C though, while 3.6.5 is installed in my `programs/local/python` directory. What should I do?

Comment: Get a virtual environment. Look into anaconda.

Comment: Are you using Mac, Windows, Linux?

Comment: @skarchmit Windows 10, 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try those methods:

1. Assume you are using `python` or `python3`command in pyinstaller, you can try to specify python3.6.5 as the python command in stead. If the script can find py3.6 while running, it can build package with it.
2. This method is similar to the last one, but use absolute path of py 3.6.5 instead of python 3.6.5 command, this can solve the binary not in PATH problem.
3. Use [pipenv](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/) or [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) to build a py3.6 dev environment, and then build the package in it.

Comment: Can i use pyCharm's automatic venv folder? I don't have the newest pyCharm, so i'm guessing it wont be python 3.7?

Comment: @TFI PyCharm is just an IDE, which is isolated with Python. The problem for old PyCharm is that it cannot recognize new features in Py3.7, but it is okay to use the auto venv folder. I have little experience on PyCharm and may not know how to create venv in that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your desired Python executable directly from /path/to/Python/bin/python.exe .

Comment: That works, but how can i create a file that is in 3.6.5?

Comment: Install pyinstaller using 3.6.5’s pip, then you should see its files in Scripts, ready to use with that version of Python.

Comment: just in case, the command is path/to/python.exe -m pip install pyinstaller

Comment: @J. Blackadar I would do that, but when i type pip3.6 install numpy for ex, it says pip3.6 isnt recognized, even though i did add it to my environment variables.when i type pip though it defaults to python 3.7's pip

Comment: @skarchmit That worked! Thanks so much! I owe my life to you haha thanks so much!

Comment: Use the pip executable in the same place as your Python 3.6.5 exe,  in /path/to/Python365/bin/pip.exe

Comment: @skarchmit  when i run the file though, it says it cant find python37.dll in the current directory, because its in 3.6.5. Can i do anything about this?

Comment: @TFI did you run it like /path/to/python365.exe /path/to/python_file.py ? Otherwise running “python” would default back to 3.7 again

Comment: @skarchmit im able to make the exe and it shows im using python 3.6.5 but when i go to run the exe, it says Traceback (most recent call last): cant find modules c_types and then tons of errors in python3.6.dll